In what way does Dante hint at a likeness between the bomb's path through the city and the exclusive vault possessed by his family?
In Fast X (2023), Dante arrived at the beach party and noticed Dom among the crowd:

Dante: He saved the Vatican. Who does that? Seriously. The Pope? God? By the way,
did you see what I did there? The ball through the city was a bit of
an homage to my family's safe. Except it was on fire.

Earlier in the movie, Dante controlled the bomb as it rolled through the streets
of Rome, but Dom minimize the explosion by redirecting it into a nearby river:
In what way does Dante hint at a likeness between the bomb's path through the city and the exclusive vault possessed by his family?

I assume this is a reference to the stealing of the vault from Dante's father in Fast 5 where they tow the vault around the city of Rio De Janeiro.




